# Using python to get data (text) from wix

Tags: python, html, urllib, velo

I'm making a python project in which I created a test wix website.
I want to get the data (text) from the wix website using urllib
so I did
url.urlopen(ADDRESS).readlines()
the problem is it did not give me anything from the text in the page and only information about the structure of the page in HTML.
how would I extricate the requested text information from the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to end up parsing the html for the information you want. Check out this python library:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

You could potentially do something like this:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
rel_data = []

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_data(self, data):
         rel_data.append(data)


parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
print(rel_data)
```

Output

```
["Test", "Parse me!"]
```

Comment: say, it's giving me an error on the import, should i use from HTMLParser import HTMLParser instead?

Comment: Yeah that will work. I should have specified that I'm using python 3. For python 2, the import is "from HTMLParser import HTMLParser."

Comment: ok that seems to work now, but it's saying i'm giving 3 parameters instead of 2 in the MyHTMLParser class, here's a screenshot - https://gyazo.com/54f3486ded8029219a52e8ab4696bd9c

Comment: Never mind, I accidently imported it wrong. it's indeed from HTMLParser import HTMLParser. thanks alot for everything!!! also I have a question , I've just seen a pyhton library called scrapy, is its role the same as HTMLParser?

Comment: I don't know too much about scrapy, but it looks like it could also be helpful. From briefly looking at it, it looks like you'd be able to query for a specific tag name if you'd prefer that. Don't forget to select best answer :)

Comment: Hey sorry I'm bothering you again but I can't understand why wouldn't my program work - https://gyazo.com/c75b94915c73c7ae3e1a0ce6e18bd631 . I printed the content as well and it does show in HTML so I can't seem to understand why wouldn't it work

Comment: Can you add your code as an edit to your question? I can then test it myself.

Comment: Wait, nevermind i just removed the parenthesis from the print and everything worked, thank you!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it.